# Deriving the strings corresponding to each attribute run in a Swift AttributedString

Tags: swift, attributedstring

I want to be able to iterate through a (value-type) `AttributedString` in Swift constructed from markdown and build arrays of words, a separate array for each attribute type in the text.

For example, if the markdown is "**bold**  **moreBold**  *italicText*", the constructed arrays will be

```
boldWords: [String] = ["bold", "moreBold"]
italicWords: [String] = ["italicText"]
```

The code will look something like this:

```
let markdown = "**bold**  **moreBold**  *italicText*"
let attributedStr = try! AttributedString(markdown: markdown)

var boldWords: [String]
var italicWords: [String]

 
for run in attributedStr.runs {
    if let intent = run.inlinePresentationIntent {
        if intent == .emphasized {
            attributedStr[run.range].backgroundColor = .red
            italicWords += word(for: run, in: attributedStr)
        }
        else if intent == .stronglyEmphasized {
        
            boldWords += word(for: run, in: attributedStr)
        }
    }
}
```

For each `run` in the attributed string, I want to derive the word in the original markdown corresponding to that run. In other words, what does the function `word()` look like?

```
func word(for run: Run, in attributedStr: AttributedString) -> String
{
    return ???
}
```

From another perspective, the `for run in attributedString.runs {...}` construct is generally used to stylize a run of characters; I want to be able to do the inverse, deriving the strings that were so stylized to start out with.

Comment: Get the run's range and subscript it onto the attributed string's characters.

Comment: Quick Draw  mcGraw! That's a wonderful answer. I'm laughing at myself. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> From another perspective, the `for run in attributedString.runs {...}` construct is generally used to stylize a run of characters; I want to be able to do the inverse, deriving the strings that were so stylized to start out with.

Like this:

```
String(attributedStr.characters[run.range])
```

> what does the function `word()` look like?
>
> ```
>  func word(for run: Run, in attributedStr: AttributedString) -> String
>  {
>      return ???
>  }
> ```

Like this:

```
func word(
    for run: AttributedString.Runs.Element, 
    in attributedStr: AttributedString
) -> String {
    String(attributedStr.characters[run.range])
}
```

Example (from Playground, using your own sample text):

```
let markdown = "**bold**  **moreBold**  *italicText*"
let attributedStr = try! AttributedString(markdown: markdown)

func word(
    for run: AttributedString.Runs.Element, 
    in attributedStr: AttributedString
) -> String {
    String(attributedStr.characters[run.range])
}

for run in attributedStr.runs {
    print(word(for: run, in: attributedStr))
}
```

Output:

```
bold
  
moreBold
  
italicText
```